# Show loader while document body is not loaded yet

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

There are some answers how to show loader while element is being loaded. My problem is different. I would like to show loader before document body is loaded.

I have ajax call

```
var url = window.location.origin+"/test.html";
showLoader();
$$.ajax({                                   
   type: "GET",                           
   url: url,                               
   success: function(data)                 
   {                                   
      document.open();                               
      document.write(data);                           
      document.close(); 
      hideLoader();                                                                                        
   }                                       
 });
```

Problem is because test.html have some scripts that delays document body loading. It shows empty blank screen until scripts are not loaded and thus document body is rendered.

Any idea how I can show loader while document body is being loaded?

Comment: You're overwriting the DOM content using `document.write(data);` with test.html. So if there has been a progress bar or similar it would be gone anyway. You need to include a loader inside test.html

Comment: Yes but it will still show blank page without loader for a second or two until document body from test.html is not rendered because of head script delay for which I don't have influence.

Comment: You can't display a loader before the document is loaded because it is the document that displays the loader.

Comment: Document is loaded but document body is not loaded yet because scripts loading delays rendering the body.

Comment: use beforesend to launch the loader, in your done do all your logic and then use always to stop the loader, here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/4xhke5pt/1/ Hope it helps

Comment: Unforunately it doesn't help, as said the problem is not timing during ajax loading but timing during document loading. I think I will parse document head and body and then use head replace and body replace instead document write.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm trying the same thing. I'm inserting a data-URI SVG animation on the background of the HTML element, but the result is the same - as long as the BODY tag isn't there, the HTML browser doesn't seem to render a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a static page loader (with css or an image) as the initial state of the page and then overwrite it with the content as soon as it's loaded via AJAX. Hopefully the following example illustrates the idea:

```js
// imitating AJAX call for the content
setTimeout(() => {
  document.write('Content loaded')
}, 3000)
```

```css
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: That won't resolve my problem. I know how to show loader until ajax call is loaded, the problem is about the time between ajax call successfully loaded and between when document body is rendered because some scripts inside head delay rendering the body.